# Creating landcover map from KML files

Tags: qgis, kml, land-cover, forest-ecology, fragstats

I am trying to understand the effect of forest fragmentation on vertebrate populations. I need to analyse my study area using Fragstats however, I couldn't find a suitable land cover map for my study area (which is in Guanacaste Province in Costa Rica). So I instead manually mapped the about 170 sq. km. surrounding my study sites using Google Earth into forests, intensively cultivated areas and moderately cultivated areas. Now I need to create a land cover map from the KML files and then create classes for each category and then analyse it using Fragstats.

Can someone tell me:

1. If the procedure which I am using for such a study is alright.
2. How can you convert KML files into classes and prepare it for use as a land cover map?

Comment: Would you prefer to convert your KML files to a vector or raster dataset?

Comment: Your approach does seem somewhat problematic. It hinges on how accurately you can determine land cover type. It's unfortunate that the National Land Cover Database does not extend outside the continental US. However, maybe you can apply their criteria to your aerial photographs. https://earthobservatory.nasa.gov/features/LandCover/land_cover_2.php

Comment: Land Cover Data for Costa Rica (Shapefile) https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/data/set/lulc-central-american-vegetation-cover-classification/docs there maybe more updated data if you contact SEDAC  > https://sedac.ciesin.columbia.edu/about

Comment: @whyzar: I want to convert it to a raster, GeoTiFF so that it can be used as an input for Fragstats.

Comment: @csk: I understand, but I am mainly trying to classify forests and non-forests at the most primary scale.

Comment: @Mapperz: :) Thank you. I will definitely write to them for more recent data.